# python socket send not working

Tags: python, sockets

Im writing a simple socket program to receive some data and reverse the contents.
When I pass the reversed contents its not being sent..

Server

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

host = socket.gethostname()

port = 1234

s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    print('Received message == ',c.recv(50))
    s = c.recv(50)[::-1]
    c.send(s)
    c.close()
```

client

```
import socket
from time import sleep
s = socket.socket()

host = socket.gethostname()

port = 1234

s.connect((host, port))

print "Sending data"
s.sendall("Hello!! How are you")
print(s.recv(1024))
```

Comment: Do you get anything printed from the server side?  You are calling `recv` twice (in the server) without a send between, but I don't know if it is getting to the second one.  My guess it that it is deadlocking on the second `recv`.

Comment: socket is IP base not domain base ! Give ip or for binding all interfaces **"0.0.0.0"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is two lines in your server

Your server calls `recv()` inside a print statement. This empties the buffer. Then you call `recv()` again, but it is already emptied by the previous statement and so it then blocks.

You need to call `recv()` and store that in `s`. Then use `s` everywhere else.

Try this for your server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

host = socket.gethostname()

port = 1234

s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    s = c.recv(50)
    print('Received message == ',s)
    c.send(s)
    c.close()
```